# How to protect sensitive data in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

i have searched couple of times but came up with nothing more than unclear answers on this matter.

Im developing a Web app which stores sensitive information (mid sized texts), and the website itself is hosted on a secure web hosting provider. But im wondering, what is the best way to store those sensitive pieces of text in MySQL without worrying about unwanted access to database (like from phpMyAdmin) and still being able to perform actions on those information on behalf of the user himself (like generating charts and creating pdfs).

Thanks and sorry for my English.

Comment: your English was perfectly fine.

Comment: Agreed with @thedugas - I've seen far worse English out of native speakers.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't control your servers, you have no security at all.

1. Control your servers.
2. Use the mysql security model to limit who can look at the data with phpmyadmin or whatnot.

If that's not good enough, you could think about encryption. However, you'd got to store the keys someplace, and now you are back where you started with mysql passwords.

Comment: What kind of encryption do you suggest ?

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use MySQL's built in encryption, see [Encryption and Compression Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html). The other major option is to use binary fields and do the encryption in your application, with AES for instance.

If you store the key on the server then anyone with access to the server and the database can decrypt the data. If that's a concern too then you'll need to consider how to get the key from the user. That can be difficult to do in a way that's both secure and convenient.

Comment: Note that this'll make indexes useless on encrypted columns. Something of a tradeoff.

Comment: What if I want my data searchable ?

Comment: I'd recommend using [Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/) or [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for full-text search, even if you don't encrypt the data. The trouble there though is if that index isn't encrypted then data could be reconstructed from that. It sounds like you probably want to completely control your servers as bmargulies suggests. You might want to consider a VPS like [linode](http://www.linode.com/?r=8e44b5c078453aa590239fbe056dfe028c5b4395) or [slicehost](http://www.slicehost.com/).

Comment: Maybe its better to describe myself better. People are submitting their diaries in our application. And they are "sensitive data" and those users are worried about our application's security. They don't want anyone but themselves be able to access those data.

Answer (score 2):

There is a system named Cryptdb designed by MIT. Cryptdb can encrypts data based on data owner password and nobody even administrators couldn't access the real data.
The team says that overhead for phpBB is 14%!

Comment: Grubbs (2017): Why Your Encrypted Database Is Not Secure: https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/468.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt the database fields using mysql encode/decode

Answer (score 1):

You should lock down your MySQL user accounts.  Consider limiting what your webapp itself can do.  Only give it the minimum necessary permissions on your database, and consider creating stored procedures to further ensure that it can only access what it requires and nothing else.

If you don't trust your hosting provider, then you need to move at least the database to somewhere that you can trust.  This further means you need ensure that your connection to your database is secured (SSL).

You should be encrypting your data.  Don't be tempted to do your own encryption, as @WhiteFang34 says, use the built in encryption.

Comment: I'm worried about the hackers mostly not normal users.